# How can I make Python print all lists of given length with elements in a fixed finite set?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

For example, I would like to be able to get all lists of length 5 with elements in the set {0,1,2,3}.

I'm sure there is an easy answer but I am stuck and I don't see how to do it!

Comment: `itertools` is the module to use, but which function depends on exactly what you want.  Do you want both `[0,0,1,2,3]` and `[0,0,3,2,1]` to appear as outputs?

Comment: This is a programming task, and not a concrete problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)' `combinations_with_replacement`:

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(4),2))
Out[18]: 
[(0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 3)]
```

(shown for `n=2` for brevity)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't count `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` as distinct, use roippi's answer. If you do, `itertools.product` (as in, "Cartesian product") works here:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.product(range(5), repeat=2)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import itertools    
list(itertools.product([0,1,2,3], repeat=5))
```

Combinations_with_replacement will catch all cases. It treats (a,b) as the same of (a,b). In practice, it will only output ordered results (ex. (1,3), but not (3,1))